# Which revision of html5lib is stable?

Tags: python, html5lib

[html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) notes that it's latest release (0.11) is somewhat old. Using the Python portion, I have recursion problems as noted in [Issue 70](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/issues/detail?id=70) and [Issue 59](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/issues/detail?id=59) but can't find a recent Mercurial revision that is stable.

The latest tip is no good, I got the following error from `python setup.py install`:

```
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/html5lib/treewalkers/_base.py to _base.pyc
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/html5lib/treewalkers/_base.py", line 40
    "data": []}
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I get the following errors at runtime:

```
    soup = parser.parse(page.read())
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 165, in parse
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 144, in _parse
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 454, in processDoctype
TypeError: insertDoctype() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

I'm using it on Python 2.5.2 with lxml and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I tried building latest revision (ceffcafb7e) on windows. 10009 tests ran, with 139 failures and 216 errors. It's ~97% stable... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of January 2010, it looks like version 0.90 is what you want:

http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/downloads/list